# different policy regarding CLSCompliant in VS2013 and VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I ran into "is not CLS-compliant" errors for some files when compiling a C# solution in VS2015, I can resolve this by adding

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
```

However, I am not sure if this is necessary in VS2013, as my coworkers didn't experience such complains and they all use VS2013.

My question is that, did VS2015 enforce the policy to ensure CLS compliance (maybe it was "recommend" but not mandatory in early version)? If so how can I disable this enforcement (I don't want to go through the whole solution to change each file, and I am not supposed to) ?

Or it's just that I didn't have a legitimate observation?

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting? It may be a 3rd party Code Quality check such as CodeCracker or Sonarlint...

Comment: the exact error message is "Type of 'XXXXX' is not CLS-compliant". I don't have any 3rd party plugins

Comment: Maybe someone added `[assembly:CLSComlpiant(true)]` anywhere in your project...

Comment: Check your AssemblyInfo.cs (for C#) file. Probably there is an [assembly:CLSCompliant(true)] there. That wouldn't explain the behavior being different in VS2013 as that attribute is treated exactly the same on both versions.